# How do you multiply each point of a linked list by a number x?

Tags: python, linked-list

Let's say there is a  linked list with a point for each integer in 123, head is 1, next is 2, next is 3, how do you multiply each element by a number, let's say 3, so that the new linked list points to 3,6,9?

Comment: Python doesn't have a linked list type built in. Are you asking about your own linked list type (in which case you should show it), or about normal Python lists (which aren't linked)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a list comprehension:

```
In [1]: lis=[1,2,3]

In [2]: [x*3 for x in lis]
Out[2]: [3, 6, 9]


In [3]: num=123

In [4]: [int(x)*4 for x in str(num)]  #convert num to a string and iterate over it
Out[4]: [4, 8, 12]

In [5]: ''.join(str(int(x)*3) for x in str(num)) #to get something like 4812
Out[5]: '4812'
```

Comment: This assumes that the linked list has an iterator defined, which may or may not be the case for custom types. Otherwise it would depend on the list.

Comment: Cool, what if it was 123 * 4 though? This method may not work for all x values that you want to multiply by? sorry for not being clear in the question about what I wanted.

Comment: @RahulSharma 123 is not a list.

Comment: Instead of `3` you place the variable which contains the multiplier.
Anyway the next time write your question correctly. This answer actually does not have anything to do with your question... it's an answer that answers the guess of your correct question.

Comment: @RahulSharma I've edited my solution, I guess this is what you wanted.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. No he wants to multiply by a different number. That is not fixed. I think

Comment: @RohitJain That isn't a big deal, just replace `3` by some other number. Though it's still not clear what he actually wants.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. Yeah that is true though. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [x * 3 for x in list1]
[3, 6, 9]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is simple:

```
def multiply(L, x):
    if L.is_empty():
        return L
    else:
        return join(L.head * x, multiply(L.tail, x))
```

Where "L.head" is the first element, L.tail is the remaining list and join is a function that put the first argument as first element of the list in the second argument(so join(1, [2,3]) ->[1,2,3]).

Python does not have simple linked-lists as built-in types. There is a `deque` type in the `collections` module, which implements a double-linked-list(and can be used as if it was a single-linked-list).

Probably you are implementing your own linked-list class(for homework)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is iterable :

```
>>> map(lambda x: x*3, [12, 1, 42])
[36, 3, 126]
```